# What should I include in the tests for Finite State Machine based framework

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, junit

I work in the financial industry and the FSM framework I'm referring to is for an Order Management System. 
It is written using Java, Spring and the rules / transitions are configured in the database.

The current tests are written using JUnit, run using Spring JUnit runner and they cover only the result states at the end of each transition.

For e.g. if an order is Modified / Amended, the integration flow tests only the final outcome i.e if the order status is now Modified in the database or not.

It doesn't test the data that was entered during the modification process actually got persisted in the database or not. There's no negative testing at all either.

My question is, what sort of test cases should a FSM based framework / application have if the framework also has a responsibility of persisting data, publishing data to the down streams, sending reports to customers etc.

Comment: The test cases should cover the functions offered by the system. Sorry, but I think your question is way too broad; and there is no sane way to give an answer here; besides the obvious: test all the things in your thing.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, what sort of test cases should a FSM based framework / application have if the framework also has a responsibility of persisting data, publishing data to the down streams, sending reports to customers etc.

Your Unittests for your Java code should not communicate to the database. This does not mean that they should not test this communication. You should replace the database accessing classes (of your OR-mapping framework) with test surrogates.

You Unittests should test any *public observable behavior* of individual units within your Java code. This includes the reaction of errors comming out of the database (forced by configuration of the test surrogates).